# Prepare segue throws nil

Tags: swift, tableview, segue

I have tableView with button. When i click this button, my ViewController changes to the second one. Also i want to get some information from the first VC to the second one but here i get my problem, my variable doesn't change.

Related code:

```
class First_VC: UIViewController {

...
    
    @IBAction func touch(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let indexPath = table.indexPath(for: sender.superview!.superview as! UITableViewCell) {
            let cell = table.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            selectedName = cell?.textLabel?.text
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
// here it works fine, if i print (selectedName) it will work like expected
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.table.dataSource =   self
        
        names() { names in
            self.heroNames = names
        }
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == "segue" else { return }
        guard let vc2 = segue.destination as? Second_VC else { return }
        vc2.name = selectedName ?? "" 
// here i get nil when print (selectedName)
    }
}

...
```

If you need any more info, feel free to ask. Trying to make an app with several ViewControllers the first time so maybe my mistake is a very silly one

Comment: are these two blocks of codes in the same file?

Comment: @willow i edited thread so it's a little bit more understandable now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass the selected name to `prepare(for:sender:)` using the `sender` parameter.

```
...
let selectedName = cell?.textLabel?.text
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: selectedName)
```

and then read it as

```
let selectedName = sender as? String ?? ""
vc2.name = selectedName
```